# Koudoku: NoMethodError on User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Posting here as I'm probably missing something obvious. I'm receiving:

```
A NoMethodError occurred in webhook#event:

undefined method 'cancel' for #<User:0x0000000a0b7520>
  vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
```

The full trace is [here](http://pastebin.com/Ys59v7r9). And the relevant block of code from [stripe_event.rb](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku/blob/master/config/initializers/stripe_event.rb) is:

```
 events.subscribe 'customer.subscription.deleted' do |event|
    stripe_id = event.data.object['customer']
    subscription = ::Subscription.find_by_stripe_id(stripe_id)
    subscription.subscription_owner.try(:cancel)
 end
```

However, it looks like it's trying to call `:cancel` on the User model - why would it do that? Shouldn't it be trying to call it on the SubscriptionsController ([here](https://github.com/andrewculver/koudoku/blob/eaad5ec77762345c9d43a1f57cb5dd6fe7c23c68/app/controllers/koudoku/subscriptions_controller.rb), line 131) which does have a method for `:cancel`?

Answer (score 0):

While it might be a controller which triggers the event, the idea of an event is to be notified about some actions independently from the trigger-source.

You can use this event to add additional code to be executed.

```
 events.subscribe 'customer.subscription.deleted' do |event|
    # get the "stripe ID" from event data
    stripe_id = event.data.object['customer']
    # find the corresponding Subscription using this ID
    subscription = ::Subscription.find_by_stripe_id(stripe_id)
    # try to call cancel on the owner (a User) of that subscription
    subscription.subscription_owner.try(:cancel)
 end
```